# SQL Server and PyODBC

Tags: python, android, ios, sql-server, kivy

I’m a hobbyist wanting to develop a basic app and just thought of a problem I may have with SQL Servers!

So drivers are OS specific and PYODBC uses the ODBC driver to work on windows. Let’s say you were to compile a python program using a Kivy GUI for iOS or Android. As it compiles all modules with it, would the driver be compiled with it and still work or would it just fail completely when you tried to connect?

If you can’t, could you create a server to receive requests and just “translate” it into pythonic form on the server-end after it was sent from the client and received by the server, so that the server can then apply the ODBC driver to send it to the SQL Server to handle the SQL request and then they just send it to the server via the driver and then the server just sends the result to the app? In other words, could you use a remote intermediary server connected to an ODBC driver to solve this problem? If this can be done, what library or API would be best to do this?

Speaking of an API, is there an API that can do this so I can look into this?

I’ve seen a few questions similar to this on Stack Overflow but the answers seem to just have different users contradicting previous ones and are full of assumptions and nothing solid so I’m not too sure how reliable they are so thought a new post was appropriate.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: When doing mobile, see: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004) So mobile will talk web service to Python (say Flask) and that talks to your database(s).